# Causes of the stochastic behaviour of voltage-gated ion channels

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, biophysics

I came up with the following electro-mechanical model of a voltage-gated ion channel, resp. of its voltage sensor as described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfcDBcDEJxQ) and [here](http://www.physiology.org/doi/pdf/10.1152/physrev.2000.80.2.555). The voltage sensor is a bistable system with two local energy minima $E_1(V)$, $E_2(V)$, the first one indicating "closed", the second one "open":

[image]

<sub>From Bezanilla, [The Voltage Sensor in Voltage-Dependent Ion Channels](http://www.physiology.org/doi/pdf/10.1152/physrev.2000.80.2.555), p. 567. 
You can interactively explore a voltage-dependent energy surface [here](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/e5UqWvm9) (schematically).</sub>

I created a spring model with Algodoo which looks like this (green: the voltage sensor (= a peptide subunit), white springs: keep it in place, blue: favours the closed state, red: simulates voltage, opens the gate):

[image]

<sub>(You can download the model [here](http://www.algodoo.com/algobox/details.php?id=179166) and explore it interactively with [Algodoo](http://www.algodoo.com/download/).)</sub>

To behave stochastically - i.e. the probability of being open $p(V) \sim e^{-\Delta Q(V)/kT}$ which presupposes a thermal equilibrium - there must be fluctuations that can lift the system above the energy barrier between the two energy minima.

My question concerns the source of these fluctuations in the real ion channel: are these **thermal (mechanical) fluctuations** (e.g. other molecules hitting or tearing the sensor) or are these **fluctuations of the membrane potential**?

Comment: And I'll note that this isn't something special with ion channels, it's true of many other types of proteins as well as non-biological molecules.

Comment: My model definitely *does* have (two distinct) energy minima, as can be seen by just watching it (above) or trying it out  (at [Algodoo](http://www.algodoo.com/algobox/details.php?id=179166)) or by checking the [Geogebra link](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/e5UqWvm9) which reflects the Algodoo model. It's not about *one* spring, but about a system of springs that definitely *may* have different and distinct energy minima.

Comment: I don't understand your second comment.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry I missed the structure of your model entirely. You can disregard. My second comment was just to state that this isn't unique to ion channels; lots and lots of other molecules or proteins have the same sort of behavior where they switch between distinct states.

Comment: @BryanKrause: Do you have any idea concerning my original question: Do the random fluctuations stem more from the immediate molecular (mechanical) environment of the voltage sensor or from the membrane potential (which in turn stems from dendritic input/PSPs).

Comment: I believe it's from the molecular environment of the voltage sensor. I also think you have to consider spatial scale here; membrane potential is best thought of at a scale of an electrotonic stretch of membrane. Molecular interactions, on the other hand, are much smaller, and at that level the precise spatial presence of individual ions could have some influence, but I wouldn't consider that "membrane potential." I personally have no idea whether that presence matters on the scale of molecular vibrations/temperature. From the perspective of neuroscience it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71273/discussion-between-hans-stricker-and-bryan-krause).

Answer (score 2):

The fluctuations arise form thermal energy and can be described by the [Eyring equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyring_equation)